# Send a message with a call.message object

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

The point is I'd like to automatically return to the start menu of my bot.

When I got `message` object, it was fine: I assigned `message.text = '/start'` and called `start_menu(message)`.

```py
@bot.message_handler()
def start_menu(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
         # ...
         # some code
         # ...

def get_something(message):
    # ...
    # some code 
    # ...
    message.text = '/start'
    start_menu(message)
```

But when I tried the same with `call.message` object from `callback_query_handler()`, I've got an error

```py
def some_function(message):
    # ...
    # some code 
    # ...
    message.text = '/start'
    start_menu(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 'some_data':
        some_function(call.message)
```

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

I've tried to create new `message` object, but got an issue with `message.from_user` field when used `bot.send_message()` from `start_menu(message)` function.

```py
def some_function(message):
    # ...
    # some code 
    # ...
    new_message = telebot.types.Message(message_id=message.message_id,
                                        chat=message.chat,
                                        content_type=["text"],
                                        date=dt.datetime.today().timestamp(),
                                        from_user=message.chat.id,
                                        options={},
                                        json_string="")
    new_message.text = '/start'
    start_menu(new_message)
```

> bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, title) > AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

So, I suppose I need to use something else to initialize `from_user` field when `new_message` defining. But got no idea already.

Help, please. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It works if pass to `from_user` field `call.message.chat` object itself.

```py
def some_function(message):
    # ...
    # some code 
    # ...
    new_message = telebot.types.Message(message_id=message.message_id,
                                        chat=message.chat,
                                        content_type=["text"],
                                        date=dt.datetime.today().timestamp(),
                                        from_user=message.chat,
                                        options={},
                                        json_string="")
    new_message.text = '/start'
    start_menu(new_message)
```